# How do I substitute overlapping matches with a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I want to find all occurences of `"BBB"` in a string and substitute them with `"D"`. For example, I have `"ABBBBC"` and want to produce `"ADBC"` and `"ABDC"`. (First substitute the first `BBB`, and then substitute the other `BBB`). Is there a nice way to do this in Perl?

```
$str = "ABBBBC";
for ( $str =~ m/B(?=BB)/g ) {
    # I match both the BBBs here, but how to substitute the relevant part?
}
```

I want to get this array: `('ADBC', 'ABDC')`, which comes from changing either of the `BBB`s to a `D`. The string `"ABBBBBC"` would give me `"ADBBC"`, `"ABDBC"` and `"ABBDC"`.

Comment: If you substitute the 1st `BBB` you get `ADBC`, where is the "other" `BBB`? Don't get it...

Comment: @Fredrik- The first is A_BBB_BC and the other AB_BBB_C. I want to make an array with all (in this case both) possible results

Comment: What output do you want for ABBBBCBBBBE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get overlapping matches, you have to play around with Perl's [`pos`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html) operator.

> **`pos SCALAR`**
>   **`pos`**
>   Returns the offset of where the last `m//g` search left off for the variable in question (`$_` is used when the variable is not specified). Note that 0 is a valid match offset. [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) indicates that the search position is reset (usually due to match failure, but can also be because no match has yet been run on the scalar).
>
> `pos` directly accesses the location used by the regexp engine to store the offset, so assigning to pos will change that offset, and so will also influence the `\G` zero-width assertion in regular expressions. Both of these effects take place for the next match, so you can't affect the position with `pos` during the current match, such as in `(?{pos() = 5})` or `s//pos() = 5/e`.
>
> Setting `pos` also resets the matched with zero-length flag, described under [Repeated Patterns Matching a Zero-length Substring in perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Repeated-Patterns-Matching-a-Zero-length-Substring).
>
> Because a failed `m//gc` match doesn't reset the offset, the return from `pos` won't change either in this case. See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "ABBBBC";
my @replaced;
while ($str =~ m/^(.*)\G(.+?)BBB(.*)$/g ) {
  push @replaced, $1 . $2 . "D" . $3;
  pos($str) = length($1) + 1;
}

print "[", join("][" => @replaced), "]\n";
```

Output:

```
$ ./prog
[ADBC][ABDC]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local our @replaced;
'ABBBBC' =~ /^(.*)BBB(.*)\z(?{ push @replaced, $1.'D'.$2 })(?!)/s;
```